# What is this bullet-dodging martial arts movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie, martial-arts

As a kid I watched a movie that was my dads. All I remember from it was there was some kind of (potentially reluctant) hero / anti hero. He's trying to shoot an (Asian?) guy who could dodge the bullets. This guy ends up training him up (perhaps) and then this hero / anti hero has the same ability. Ability in the ninja sense I think. One of these powers was the ability to run across liquid surfaces I think.

What I'm pretty sure on:

1. Western cop / hero / anti hero tries to shoot an Asian fella who can dodge bullets
2. At some point after the training he is being chased and he runs across wet concrete (or similar) whereas the bad guy falls straight in.

I have a feeling it was Charles Bronson or someone like that, and could have been quite b movie like.

Comment: Fred Ward was the main actor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it [Remo Williams: The Adventure Begins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089901/),

> where An officially "dead" cop is trained to become an extraordinarily
>   unique assassin in service of the US president.

Given answer by reading [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090325075903AATi5nT) Yahoo question and its selected answer.

Comment: "The Korean is the most perfect creature ever to sanctify the Earth with the imprint of his foot."  - Chun, Master of Shinanju.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like "[Remo Williams: The Adventure Begins](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_lKShbp3nw)." The cheesy dodging of bullets is a component of the fictional martial art Shinanju.